# .NET creating an email with attachments in Office 2010

Tags: .net, email, c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-2010

I know with an mailto link you can open your defautl mail client and populate a subject and a title. I need to do something similar but also attach a document.

All my users will be using Outlook 2010 and it will be set as there default mail client. It only needs to work for that case.

How can you create an email that opens up the Outlook new message window and populates the attachment field?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a reference to the Outlook COM library, then something like this should work:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Application Object
    /// </summary>
    public static OL.Application Application
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as OL.Application;
            }
            catch (COMException)
            {
                return new OL.Application();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prepare An Email In Outlook
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ToAddress"></param>
    /// <param name="Subject"></param>
    /// <param name="Body"></param>
    /// <param name="Attachment"></param>
    public static void CreateEmail(string ToAddress, string Subject, string Body, string AttachmentFileName)
    {
        //Create an instance of Outlook (or use existing instance if it already exists
        var olApp = Application;

        // Create a mail item
        var olMail = olApp.CreateItem(OL.OlItemType.olMailItem) as OL.MailItem;
        olMail.Subject = Subject;
        olMail.To = ToAddress;

        // Set Body
        olMail.Body = Body;

        // Add Attachment
        string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AttachmentFileName);
        olMail.Attachments.Add(AttachmentFileName, OL.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, name);

        // Display Mail Window
        olMail.Display();
    }
```

For this to work you would also need:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using OL = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Comment: Do I just need to reference Office and Outlook Object library's?

Comment: I keep getting 'object' does not contain a definition for 'To' and no extension method 'To' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) so I think the reference is wrong..

Comment: I was using VS2010 with .Net 4, this made the olMail item a dynamic object and hence it worked. I will update the code so that olMail is cast to the appropriate type.